# LINQ Splitting and group by resulting property

Tags: linq, split, group-by

I have an object and one of the properties of the object is a comma delimited list of names e.g.

```
IList<Audits> auditData = new List<Audits>();
auditData.Add(new Audit
              {
                  Auditors = "Adam West, George Best",
                  TimeSpent = 7
              });

auditData.Add(new Audit
              {
                  Auditors = "Adam West",
                  TimeSpent = 5
              });

auditData.Add(new Audit
              {
                   Auditors = "Adam West, George Best, Elvis Presley",
                   TimeSpent = 3
              });
```

I'd like to use LINQ to query this data, split the auditors property, group by auditor and total the timespent for each auditor, to give me a list of auditors with time spent against each one e.g.

Adam West 15,
George Best 10,
Elvis Presley 3

Can anyone assist me in doing that?  Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any reason why `Auditors` couldn't be a `List<string>` to start with?

Comment: i second with JonSkeet, the solution is easier if you are using a List<string> type for Auditors. (it supports IEn)

Comment: I'd also like it to start off as a list - unfortunately, this is part of an existing system and I don't have control of this property being comma delimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var query =
    from a in auditData
    let auditors = a.Auditors.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim())
    from au in auditors
    group a.TimeSpent by au into g
    select new { Auditor = g.Key, TimeSpent = g.Sum() };
```

Answer (score 3):

Using lambdas:

```
var results =
    auditData
        // Flatten list - to list of individual auditors and time spent
        .SelectMany(
            audit => audit.Auditors.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()),
            (audit, auditorName) => new
            {
                Auditor = auditorName,
                TimeSpent = audit.TimeSpent,
            })
        // Group by auditor name
        .GroupBy(a => a.Auditor)
        // Sum time spent
        .Select(auditorGroup => new
        {
            Auditor = auditorGroup.Key,
            TotalTimeSpent = auditorGroup.Sum(a => a.TimeSpent)
        })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = auditData.Select(audit => audit.Auditors.Split(',').ToDictionary(a => a, a => audit.TimeSpent))
            .SelectMany(a => a)
            .GroupBy(a => a.Key)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, s => s.Sum(g => g.Value));
```

First split the strings and convert to KeyValue pairs. Then flatten the dictionaries into a single one. Then group and sum.